# Imports with Pydev/Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, import, pydev, reload

I'm working with the interactive console in eclipse, and reload does not show updated functions in my code.  My code was :

```
def func1():  
    return 1  
def func2():  
    return 2
```

but when I changed it to

```
def afunc1():  
    return 1  
def func2():  
    return 2  
def func1():  
    return 3
```

and ran imp.reload(TestMod), I got a `'module' object has no attribute 'afunc1()'`.
Also, sometimes the functions are loaded and sometimes they are not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out, eclipse was not saving the file (or not saving it to the correct location) when I hit ctl-s.  To get it to work, I had to right click the file name in the Package Explorer and select open with PyDev and save it under that

Comment: Also a quick tip, sometimes I do a Project->Clean on my projects if it seems like weird errors are showing up.